# The object name 'DBSourceServer.SourceDWHTemp.dbo.SourceTable1' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have DBServer1 and DBServer2 and want to load the data from DBSourceServer to DBTargetServer in SQL Server stored procedure.
SourceDB and SourceDWHTemp resides in DBServer1.
TargetDB resides in DBServer2.
We are applying ETL techniques in the SourceDB Stored Procedure script and intermediate tables are storing in SourceDWHTemp. Final data will be loaded into TargetDWHDB tables.
We are facing issues to run the script.

```
    ---- We are running this script in [TargetDB]  database and DBTargetServer machine
Use [TargetDWHDB]    
select * from [DBSourceServer].[SourceDWHTemp].[dbo].[SourceTable1]      ----- It is successfully executing
DROP TABLE [DBSourceServer].[SourceDWHTemp].[dbo].[SourceTable1]    -----
```

This is throwing the below error message

Error Message:

> Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
> The object name 'DBSourceServer.SourceDWHTemp.dbo.SourceTable1' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.
> Completion time: 2021-06-02T18:21:31.6669423+08:00

How to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't drop a table on a linked server (at least not using that syntax).

Comment: Even I can not truncate this:

TRUNCATE TABLE [DBSourceServer].[SourceDWHTemp].[dbo].[SourceTable1]    ----- This is throwing the below error message

Msg 2702, Level 16, State 2, Line 15
Database 'SourceDWHTemp' does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below Execute option.

```sql
EXECUTE ( 'DROP TABLE .[SourceDWHTemp].[dbo].[SourceTable1] ' ) AT [DBSourceServer];
```

[Read more on this issue](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/drop-table-on-linked-server)